# choosing correct form according to form input's name

Tags: python, mechanize

I want to submit forms in multiple websites. Usually I can't exactly know the form name or form id, but I know the input name that I want to submit.

Let's say there is a website which has couple of forms inside it. My code should check all of the forms, if one of them has a input value named "birthday" it will submit that form. If multiple forms has it, it will submit them all.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can basically loop over all forms and skip forms that don't contain the desired input:

```
for form in br.forms():
    if not form.find_control(name="birthday"):
         continue
    # fill form and submit here
```

More about `find_control()` [here](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html).

Comment: so how can I select form since I don't know the form name?

Comment: @RobertZunr that's what I'm saying, iterate over all of them and filter.

Comment: I'm skipping the forms which has no "birthday" input. But what about the rest. How can I find the form name to submit the "birthday" value

Answer (score 0):

You are gonna need to use an [iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/6209196) to check all the forms in the website. In this case we will be using `for`. But this doesn't let us know about which form we are working on, it just lets us use it. So we are going to assign 0(the first form's ID) to a variable and add 1 to it as we change forms when a new iteration/loop starts.

```
currentForm = 0
for form in br.forms(): # For every form in the website
        currentForm += 1 # Add 1 to the current form so that the script knows which form we will be working next
        if not forms.find_control(name = "birthday"): # If the form isn't about birthday
                continue # Go to the next iteration / loop ignoring the statements below
        br.select_form(nr = currentForm) # Select the birthday form
        br.form["birthday"] = "Fill this with what you want" # Writing to the form
        br.submit() # Submit the working form
```

Note: `x += y` is equal to `x = x + y`